# Windows 11 on Qemu SAP install prompt

Tags: windows, installation

I downloaded the latest Windows 11 ISO direct from microsoft.com. As of time of writing the current release file is named, `Win11_22H2_English_x64.iso`.

I installed Windows 11 (Pro) using that ISO in a Qemu VM and everything seems fine until after the `Checking for updates.` install screen. Despite what the [Microsoft documentation states](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-make-clean-install-of-windows-11/789f6891-7261-4c40-a632-6a44e53a3e30) I am never prompted with steps 16, 17, 18, etc. My installation goes straight from `Checking for updates.` to `Let's set things up for your work or school`.

[image: screenshot of the Windows 11 install screen that says, "Let's set things up for your work or school"]

I'm prompted with an SAP login screen titled, "Let's set things up for your work or school".

I see [others have encountered this issue, but I'm not sure there's a clear answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/forced-to-sign-in-to-work-or-school-account-during/0e907fa5-9a49-42ef-83c2-613a9319c1e4).

I've tried:

- Purposefully removing the network connection, which seems to totally prevent Windows 11 Installation and so is not a workaround
- Reinstalling to verify that I am using the `Windows 11 Pro` distribution option
- Trying to use my consumer/standard user live.com login information at this SAP login screen
- Using a valid Windows "Ultimate" (Pro) product key. *Not* an Education/Student edition key
- Selecting the `I don't have a product key` option during installation

I do not have an SAP work or school account and am installing as a regular consumer end user. I do not see how I can proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like [Windows Autopilot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/autopilot/windows-autopilot) is trying to enroll your device as a SAP owned company device.
This happens when Windows thinks the hash of the hardware matches the hash of Autopilot enabled device in an Azure/Microsoft Endpoint tenant.

I would try changing your QEMU config, like changing the disk serial or NIC MAC address and see if it happens again when trying to install Windows. It might be easiest to just delete the VM and create it again.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Setting a serial and model number on my virtual disks got this working. I used the numbers off a real drive as a template and now the Windows 11 install works normally as I'd expect for an end-user